# How to programatically export .mlapp to .m?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

In the App Designer there is an option `Save -> Export to .m File...`

Is there a function available to do the same from the Matlab Command Window?

I'm aiming for something I can use as a git precommit hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`type`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/type.html) function:

```matlab
diary app_exported.m
type app.mlapp
diary off
```

or from the command line:

```sh
matlab -batch 'type app.mlapp' > app_exported.m
```